# Why does my Spring AOP aspect work in my unit test but not my webapp?

Tags: spring, aop

I have an aspect working correctly in my unit tests, a log message is printed from the actual method, and afterwards from the aspect applied.

When running my webapp though, I only see the result of the '@afterReturning' advice applied, my method does not execute first.

My config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

  <bean id="loggingAspect" class="com.mypackage.MyAspect" />

</beans>
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Information you provided in not enough to analyze. So check below things in your web app,

1) Verify that the method you are expecting to be intercepted by your advice, belongs to spring bean class & not some other servlet or other class defined outside spring. If any class is not initialized through spring then aop advice can not be applied to that class.

2) Verify that above aop & advice configs are put in proper context xml for spring. Like in case of spring-mvc, you have to explicitely define the name of your application context xml. And in that application context xml only you have to write aop configurations.

3) Verify if your pointcut is appropriate to find exact class & method for advice.

See if these things are in place.